# Is $P_{s,t}f(X_s)$ the same than $P_{s,t}(X_s,\mathbb R )$?

Tags: probability

In the Book of Yor-Revus (continuous martingales and Brownian motion), they define $$P_{s,t}(X_s,A):=\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid \sigma (X_u : u\leq s)).$$
And after they say that one can prove with usual argument that $$\mathbb E[f(X_t)\mid \sigma (X_s:u\leq s)]=P_{s,t}f(X_s).$$
But they didn't defined what is $P_{s,t}f(X_s)$.

**Q1)** Is it implicitly $P_{s,t}(f(X_s),\mathbb R)$ ?

**Q2)** Also, is $P_{s,t}(X_s,A)$ the same than $\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid X_s)$ ? Because $P_{s,t}(X_s,A)$ depend on $s,t$ and $X_s$ only, as $\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid X_s)$. So, since they defined $$P_{s,t}(X_s,A)=\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid \sigma (X_u : u\leq s))$$

may be the idea is to define $$\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid \sigma (X_u : u\leq s)):=\mathbb P(X_t\in A\mid X_s) \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 1):

I know this book, but without context, your question is not really clear. Anyway. In my memory, we consider a process $X$ s.t. there are transition probabilities $P_{s,t}$ s.t. $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{X_t\in A\}}\mid \mathcal F_s]=:\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid \mathcal F_s\}=P_{s,t}(X_s,A),\tag{D}$$
where $\mathcal F_s:=\sigma (X_u\mid u\leq s)$ (the existence of such a process is avoided at this point, so, suppose it does).

- The $P_{s,t}$ are transition probabilities mean that $P_{t,s}$ are kernels s.t. $P_{s,t}(x,E)=1$ for all $x\in E$, where $E$ is the state space. In particular, we **define** $$P_{s,t}f(x):=\int_E f(y)P_{s,t}(x,\mathrm d y).$$ 
  So, in somehow the $P_{t,s}$ act on a set of function. Now, what have to prove is that the fact that $(D)$ hold, then so is $$\mathbb E[f(X_t)\mid \mathcal F_s]=P_{s,t}f(X_s)=\int_E f(y)P_{s,t}(X_s,\mathrm d y).$$
- For you other question, it's indeed the idea. But the notation $\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_s\}$ is less convenient espacially when you work with homogeneous transition function.